# Retrofit 2: How to get error message returns by remote server?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I call a specific web service on my plateform; this web service can return error cases, like this one:

```
Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "email",
      "code": "Email",
      "message": "Value of field 'email' must have a valid e-mail format"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my callback I can't read the message (always empty!). But on my logs, I can see the right message:

```
01:02:53.295 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: <-- 422 Unprocessable Entity: https://xxxxxx/users (1349ms)
11-04 01:02:53.295 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 04 Nov 2016 14:49:12 GMT
11-04 01:02:53.295 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
11-04 01:02:53.295 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
11-04 01:02:53.295 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
11-04 01:02:53.295 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: Server: nginx
11-04 01:02:53.295 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: **{"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"field":"password","code":"TooShort","message":"Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 6 caract\u00e8res"}]}**
11-04 01:02:53.299 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (150-byte body)
```

And this is my callback:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<T>call, Response<T> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        onSuccessful(response.code(), response.body());

    } else {
        /// READ THE ERROR MESSAGE
        response.errorBody().string() > returns nothing!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the status code and message by following way

```
Log.d("stattus_code",""+response.raw().code())
Log.d("stattus_code",""+response.raw().message())
```

So it will be something like this

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<T>call, Response<T> response) {

    Log.d("stattus_code",""+response.raw().code())
    Log.d("stattus_code",""+response.raw().message())
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        onSuccessful(response.code(), response.body());

    } else {
        /// READ THE ERROR MESSAGE
        response.errorBody().string() > returns nothing!
    }
}
```

Comment: No Shuvro. If I print raw().message() : "Unprocessable Entity:". that's it. It's not the server message.

Comment: what do you mean by server message ? What you actually want to print ?

Comment: @anthony do you want to print this "message":"Validation Failed"?

Comment: Yes! This is the message logged on OkHttp logs: 11-04 01:02:53.295 19015-19371/com.xx D/OkHttp: **{"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"field":"password","code":"TooShort","message":"Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 6 caract\u00e8res"}]}**

Comment: just "message":"Validation Failed"  or  {"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"field":"password","code":"TooShort","mes‌​sage":"Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 6 caract\u00e8res"}]}

Comment: The complete json message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127398/discussion-between-shuvro-and-anthony).

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can get the error body

```
  if (response != null && response.errorBody() != null) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
    String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
    String errors =  jsonObject.getString("errors");
  }
```